# How to capitalize $2 in preg_replace?

Tags: tags, preg-match

I run a community site (built by hand using html, css, and php) for my wow guild. Recently, my members have demanded the ability to use tags like @username in their posts, which would then link to the users page. I already have this script, as listed below:

```
<?php

$string = '@user really?';

if (preg_match('/(^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', $string))
{

$string = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '<a href="user/$2">@$2</a>', $string);

echo $string;
}
else {

echo $string;

}

?>
```

This works fine, and I notice that the $2 is the user's name, but, since all user's names start with capital letters, the $2 needs to be capitalized, and not everyone does that. Is there a way to code it to automatically capitalize $2, or should I just tell users to remember to capitalize?

Thanx in advance,
Steven

Answer (score 0):

use ucfirst ($2) to capitalize the first character
and strtoupper($2) if you want it all capital

Answer (score 0):

I added more preg_replace and it now links to user no matter how u type name, as long as u have @ symbol (@user, @USER, @User, @uSER, etc...). for anyone needing my solution, I will post it below:

```
<?php

$proper_str = "going to battle with @ADROK";

$proper_str = ucfirst(strtolower($proper_str));

$proper_str = preg_replace('/@[a-z]/e', 'ucfirst(strtoupper("$0"))', $proper_str);

$proper_str = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', ' <a href="user/$2">@$2</a>', $proper_str);

echo $proper_str;

?>
```

and if you change somethings around and make it:

```
<?php

$proper_str = "going to battle with e@mail.com";

if (preg_match('/(^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', $proper_str))

{

$proper_str = ucfirst(strtolower($proper_str));

$proper_str = preg_replace('/@[a-z]/e', 'ucfirst(strtoupper("$0"))', $proper_str);

$proper_str = preg_replace('/(^|\s)@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', ' <a href="user/$2">@$2</a>', $proper_str);

echo $proper_str;

} else {

$proper_str = ucfirst("$proper_str");

echo $proper_str;

}

?>
```

Then it will leave email addresses alone and make sure first letter of post is capitalized!